# Variable defined with a reserved word const

Tags: javascript

Why does the following code snippet below have such a result?
variables of type CONST could not have their value changed right?

```
const theDog = {
  name: 'Totó',
  guardian: { name: 'Alan Turing' }
}
const otherDog = { ...theDog, name: 'Tulipa' }
otherDog.guardian.name = 'Maria Luiza'
```

theDog? `{ name: 'Totó', guardian: { name: 'Maria Luiza' } }`

Comment: The value of the object can't be changed, but its properties still can be. You can use `const otherDog = { ...theDog, guardian: {...theDog.guardian}, name: 'Tulipa' }` to avoid this issue in your example.

Comment: Related question: [When to use const with objects in JavaScript?](/q/44604212/5764553)

Comment: `otherDog` is a shallow copy of `theDog`. Check out [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/184710/3982562) and/or have a look at [the Wikipedia page about shallow copying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying#Shallow_copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of the object can't be changed, but its properties still can be. You can use object spread syntax on the `guardian` property to avoid this issue.

```js
const theDog = {
 name: 'Totó',
 guardian: { name: 'Alan Turing' }
}
const otherDog = { ...theDog, guardian: {...theDog.guardian}, name: 'Tulipa' }
otherDog.guardian.name = 'Maria Luiza'
console.log(theDog);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the object is copied with its internal references included, this `theDog.guardian` and `otherDog.guardian` refer to the same object.

The solution would be to clone the whole object recursively:

```js
const theDog = {
 name: 'Totó',
 guardian: { name: 'Alan Turing' }
}
const otherDog = Object.assign({}, theDog, {
    name: 'Tulipa'
});
otherDog.guardian.name = 'Maria Luiza'
```

> Also `const` only specifies that the variable cannot be changed, not the referenced objects

Answer (score 0):

So, at first you are declaring one variable `theDog` and the second one is just a reference to the first one. When you are editing the second one you are editing the first one.

If you don't want this, you can use

```
const resultObject = Object.assign({}, theDog);
```

to clone it.